# How to refer to parent package in relative package import?

Tags: scala, import, package

I'd like to import package `com.example.abc` from `com.example.iop` in similar manner to bash expression `../abc`.

Is this possible in Scala? I've read couple of articles but they say nothing about my case.

---

Update: I've discovered code suitable for simple uses (I've seen it in some project while ago):

```
package com.example
package com.example.abc

import iop
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That is simply not possible -- same as in Java.

Answer (score 4):

Your updated package structure has a hint of the solution, but isn't quite right. You can live in multiple packages, including a broad parent package defined by the first package statement – subsequent statements refine the tree.

```
package com.foo   //        we're in: com.foo
package bar       //   we're also in: com.foo.bar
package wibble    //   we're also in: com.foo.bar.wibble

import frobble._  //   this could be com.foo.frobble or com.foo.bar.frobble or com.foo.bar.wibble.frobble
```

Obviously, things can get confusing if you have multiple packages with the same name, but the compiler asks you politely to sort that out.